# Save timestamp in sqlite in iOS

Tags: swift, sqlite, timestamp

I have a SQLite Database and in one column I want to store timestamp get using following method. What column data type should I set.

```
let timestamp = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
```

Comment: Don't use `NSDate` in Swift. Use `Date`.

Comment: It's a number. The data type seems fairly obvious. What choices have you considered?

Comment: Okay, but what about store time stamp in sqlite. What data type I should set for column?

Comment: timeIntervalSince1970 returns TimeInterval a.k.a Double, use: REAL in sqlite

Comment: Yes it's number so I am planning to set Real type

Comment: Thanks CjCoax for information. I will try and update if any issue face

Comment: FYI -please see [What datatypes does SQLite support?](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q2)

Comment: Yes I set the Real and working for me. Thanks friends for such information